# Anticipate the file size of on writing memorystream to file

Tags: c#, memory, binary

I would like to anticipate the exact size of my file before writing it in my device, to handle the error or prevent the crash in case there is no space in the corresponding drive. So I have this simple console script, that generates the file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace myNamespace
{
     class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            byte[] myByteArray = new byte[100];
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            string fileName = "E:\\myFile.mine";
            FileStream myFs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
            BinaryWriter toStreamWriter = new BinaryWriter(stream);

            BinaryWriter toFileWriter = new BinaryWriter(myFs, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            myFs.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
                toStreamWriter.Write(i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"allocated memory: {stream.Capacity}" );
            Console.WriteLine($"stream lenght {stream.Length}");
            Console.WriteLine($"file size: {(stream.Length / 4) * 4.096 }");

            toFileWriter.Write(stream.ToArray());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I got to the point when I get to anticipate the size of the file.
I will be `stream.Length / 4) * 4.096`, but as long an the ramainder of `stream.Length / 4` is 0.
For example for the case of adding 13589 integers to the stream

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13589; i++) {
    toStreamWriter.Write(i);
}
```

I get that the file size is  55660,544 bytes in the script, but then its 57344 bytes in the explorer.

[image]

Same result as if the integers added would have been 14000 instead of 13589.

How can I anticipate the exact size of my created file when the remainder of `stream.Length / 4` is not 0?

Edit: For the potential helper running the script you need to delete the created file every time the script is run! Of course use a path and fileName of your choice :)

Regarding the relation `stream.Length / 4) * 4.096`, the 4 is coming for the byte size, and I guess that the 4.096 comes from the array and file generation, however any further explanation would be much appreciated.

Edit2: Check that if the pending results  are logged with:

```
for (int i = 13589; i <= 14000; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine($"result for {i} : {(i*4 / 4) * 4.096} ");
}
```

You obtain:

```
....
result for 13991 : 57307,136
result for 13992 : 57311,232
result for 13993 : 57315,328
result for 13994 : 57319,424
result for 13995 : 57323,52
result for 13996 : 57327,616
result for 13997 : 57331,712
result for 13998 : 57335,808
result for 13999 : 57339,904
result for 14000 : 57344
```

So I assume that file size fits the next cluster + byteStream size with no decimal reminder. Would this file size set logic make sense for the file size anrticipation? If the stream is very big also?

Comment: Your end goal is not really possible. Keep in mind that a file has a file size and a size on disk. Which are usually different. And keep in mind that your process is probably not the only one running. Meaning that other processes will write to disk and change the remaining disk space between your check and you actually writing the file to disk. Handle out of space with an exception thrown by the writing function.

Comment: side note: writing to a MemoryStream *then* a file us usually undesirable (and also imposes artificial size constraints); and even if you do: don't use `ToArray()`; there are APIs like `TryGetBuffer` or `CopyTo` that would be hugely preferable over `ToArray()`

Comment: @sbecker thanks for your proposal. Other process running would be for the space availability problem, that is not what I am asking. My end goal is to put the problem in context.  On the other hand file size and a size on disk, which are different, can be anticipated with `stream.Length / 4` and `stream.Length / 4) * 4.096` respectively when the `stream.Length / 4)` ramainder is 0, and c# sets that somehow, so I don't think that having those two sizes and being different have something to do in the feasabily of what I am asking, the anticipation of the created file size

Comment: Are you trying to work out how many disk clusters your file will occupy, or are you trying to work out how many bytes big the file will be?

Comment: @sbecker btw I intended to apply your Handle out of space with an exception thrown by the writing function proposal :)

Comment: @CaiusJard how many bites the file will be

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit thick, but why is that not just stream.Length? Why are you doing this fudge with 4/4.096ths ?

Comment: On any file system accessed by Windows, the minimum granularity for saving data is the cluster size; on NTFS this is typically 4096 bytes but can be wildly different on other file systems (think about network drives stored on UNIX/Linux hosts, NetApp appliances, or similar; also, many NAS/SAN systems have transparent compression that you cannot even take into account). I feel that it would be best to make a rough estimate in megabytes, and make sure you have at least that amount of free space, given that any file system with less than 1MB of free space will probably give you trouble anyway.

Comment: @CaiusJard just to get the exact file size. My memory steam can be huge, so I would like to understand how this size is set

Comment: The size of the file will be the length of the stream. The "size on disk" you show in your screenshot is "how many disk clusters the file occupies" This is not the size of the file. Disks are divided into buckets of a regular length, and files are spread across buckets. If a file size is exactly divisible by the bucket size, then it occupies only full buckets. In any other case the last bucket is part full, but is unusable for any other file. You'll note that your "size on disk" of 57344 is exactly divisible by  4096 and 8192 so your disk bucket (cluster) size is one of these, but yo

Comment: oh, I am not familiarized with the disk clusters issue. So regarding your previous question, I guess I am after both, the disk clusters your file will occupy,and how many bytes big the file will be. I want to know the file size on disk after all

Comment: But you don't really, because whether the tail of the file fills the last cluster or not, the rest of the cluster is unusable for any other file.. Unless you're going to code so, considering the file size, it'll occupy all but e.g. the last available cluster, then you can say "well, there are 3 clusters of space left, I know the cluster size is X so my file of size X+1 bytes will occupy two of the free clusters, - i'll write the file because it won't *completely* fill the disk, so not my fault the disk is full..."

Comment: ..all in, if you want to implement this, I'd go with dumetrelo's suggestion: have a buffer size of some configurable number of megabytes, and when disk free space gets below this, send alerts rather than writing the file.. That way you don't directly cause some horrible system problem elsewhere and you don't need to get into the navel fluff detail  of exactly how many X will be left after you write your file.. Or you can jsut fill the disk, catch the crash and see if the system is still stable enough to send the alert (but in the spirit of "be nice when sharing resources" I wouldn't..)

Comment: thanks @dumetrulo for the insight. I see. So seems that to anticipate the file size in a generic way would a bit out of reach. However for my problem, the file to save would be generated locally and in windows systems. In case that makes any improvement on the 4096 byte reliability in the case of it being harcoded. My question after all would be where this value is coming from, and if it could be achieved dynamically in case it changes (maybe from the OS) to anticipate the file size in a robust way :)

Comment: You could probably query the system about the cluster size, but you have not really presented the actual problem you are trying to solve. Unless you have some very specific problem, you are probably better of by just writing to disk and let the system handle the rest. If you are worried about filling the disk, some kind of automatic deletion of old data, or warnings about nearly full disk may be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Regarding "but you have not really presented the actual problem" I think its clear. I want to know the file size before the file creation as I believe it can retrieved with the memorystream size, that is available at the time of the `toFileWriter.Write(stream.ToArray());`. Let me know what is not clear about the problem definition

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from the comments, the question is about how to get the actual file size of the file. Not the file size on disk. And your code is actually almost correct in doing so.

The math is pretty basic. In your example, you create a file stream and write a 100 byte long array to the file stream. Then you create memory stream and write 30000 integers into the memory stream. Then you write the memory stream into the file stream. Considering that each integer here is 4 byte long, as specified by C#, the resulting file has a file size of (30000 * 4) + 100 = 120100 bytes. At least for me, it's exactly what the file properties say in the Windows Explorer.

You could get the same result a bit easier with the following code:

```
FileStream myFs = new FileStream("test.file", FileMode.CreateNew);
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[100];
myFs.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);

BinaryWriter toFileWriter = new BinaryWriter(myFs, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++)
{
    toFileWriter.Write(i);
}

Console.WriteLine($"stream lenght {myFs.Length}");
myFs.Close();
```

This will return a stream length of 120100 bytes.

In case I misunderstood your question and comments and you were actually trying to get the file size on disk:
Don't go there. You cannot reliably predict the file size on disk due to variable circumstances. For example, file compression, encryption, various RAID types, various file systems, various disk types, various operating systems.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So guess that the logic I mention that seems to be applied in to obtain the file size ( the file size that  fits the next cluster + byteStream size with no decimal reminder) is not useful....